# how to get the minor of three column values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

The common function to get the minor value of a column is `min(column)`, but what I want to do is to get the minor value of a row, based on the values of 3 columns. For example, using the following base table:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    2 |    1 |    3 |
|   10 |    0 |    1 |
|   13 |   12 |    2 |
+------+------+------+
```

I want to query it as:

```
+-----------+
| min_value |
+-----------+
|         1 |
|         0 |
|         2 |
+-----------+
```

I found a solution as follows, but for SQL, not Postgresql. So I am not getting it to work in postgresql:

```sql
    select
        (
            select min(minCol)
            from (values (t.col1), (t.col2), (t.col3)) as minCol(minCol)
        ) as minCol
    from t
```

I could write something using `case` statement but I would like to write a query like the above for postgresql. Is this possible?

Comment: "*But for SQL*" makes no sense- PostgreSQL does use SQL as its query language (SQL is the definition of a query language for relational databases, not the name of a specific database product),

Comment: Sorry about this confusion, as I mentioned in the comment below, I am such a noob. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `least()` (and `greatest()` for the maximum)

```
select least(col1, col2, col3) as min_value
from the_table
```

Comment: tnx. Sorry about the noob question. I am new on database querying.